# pdf attachment to mailgun api android

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2, mailgun

i can successfully send email via mail gun and the file is also received in email but its empty
this is how im getting file

```
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, NormalFilePickActivity.class);
    intent4.putExtra(Constant.MAX_NUMBER, 1);
    intent4.putExtra(NormalFilePickActivity.SUFFIX, new String[]{"pdf"});
    startActivityForResult(intent4, Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE);


    if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_CODE_PICK_FILE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             ArrayList<NormalFile> list = null;
            if (data != null) {
          list=data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constant.RESULT_PICK_FILE);
                    filePath = list.get(0).getPath();
                    file = FileUtils.getFileByPath(filePath);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: file path " + filePath);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: file absolute path " + 
                    file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

this is how im sending it to mail gun api

my method

```
@Multipart
@POST("messages")
Call<ResponseBody> sendEmail1(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```

and creating and parsing requestbody

```
    RequestBody surveyBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("pdf/*"), file);

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("to", to)
            .addFormDataPart("from", CurrentUser.getEmail())
            .addFormDataPart("subject", subject)
            .addFormDataPart("text", body)
            .addFormDataPart("attachment", "file", surveyBody)
            .build();
```

where im wrong here its been a week and i cant find solution i know the mistake is going to be somewhere in parsing

Comment: What is the value of filePath? And what is the value of file.getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: `if (list.size() != 0 || list != null)` You are checking for null too late.

Comment: file path /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/regression.pdf
                                          file absolute path /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/regression.pdf

Comment: updated the code for check... still not file im receiving in email is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was i was not sending the file with extension... so just placed filename.pdf and its working now